# How do I format number in cellTemplate using jquery Devextreme?

Tags: devextreme

I want to customize my debit and credit column. When there is amount, it will become `blue color` and when click on it, it will `show pop up`. If the `amount is zero` then it will be `blank`. The problem is when I using cellTemplate to customize the cell, the customizeText and the format not working. Anyone have idea on it? Please see my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ao1trcb/2/)

At first by using this, I able to make the zero values become blank (see debit column)

```
{
  dataField: "debit",
  caption: "DEBIT",
  dataType: "number",
  width: 150,
  format: "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)",
  customizeText: function(cellInfo) {
    if (cellInfo.valueText === "0.00") {
      return " ";
    } else {
      return cellInfo.valueText;
    }
  },
}
```

after I add cellTemplate, the customizeText and the format not working. The amount didnt format well and the zero didnt become blank. (see credit column)

```
{
dataField: "credit",
  caption: "CREDIT",
  dataType: "number",
  width: 150,
  format: "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)",
  customizeText: function(cellInfo) {
    if (cellInfo.valueText === "0.00") {
      return " ";
    } else {
      return cellInfo.valueText;
    }
  },
  cellTemplate: function(container, cellInfo) {
    var credit = cellInfo.data.credit;

    if (credit !== "0.0000") {
      var color1 = "blue"
    }
    $('<a/>').addClass('dx-link')
      .text(cellInfo.data.credit)
      .css("color", color1)
      .on('dxclick', function() {
       $("#popup").dxPopup("instance").show();
$("#txt").dxTextArea("instance").option("value", cellInfo.data.credit);
      })
      .appendTo(container);
  }
}
```

My Current Output

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 0):

When you use `cellTemplate` the `format` and `customizeText` are ignored. When using `cellTemplate` you'll have to format the value by hand.